# Open Source Social Bookmarking CMS?

Tags: open-source, cms

I am looking for an open source social bookmarking site CMS so I can build a site like delicious with it for my organization. This will be deployed in the internal LAN.

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

How about http://www.drigg-code.org/ 
Based on drupal, it's basically a digg clone.

Example website based on drigg : http://www.fsdaily.com/

Answer (score 1):

[SemanticScuttle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/semanticscuttle/) is a clone of del.icio.us. Take a look at the [demo](http://festic.fr/semanticscuttle/demo/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Pligg CMS. If you want to learn how to install Pligg on your website, click [here](http://www.spotht.com/2010/04/how-to-install-pligg-cms-on-your.html).